# Same vue.config.js producing different results when running npm run build 2 times in a row

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Running production build sometimes produces different size and slightly different content.
In 9 of 10 cases, it works as expected producing the same output and hash result. But sometimes in 1 case of 10, it creates slightly different .js file (see the diff picture below).

Is there a way to fix that behaviour? Here’s the differences of the output .js file shown by DiffMerge.

[image: DiffMerge window showing differences]

vue.config.js:

```
const { ElementPlusResolver } = require('unplugin-vue-components/resolvers');
 const path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
   filenameHashing: false,
   chainWebpack: config => {config.optimization.minimize(false);},
   pages: {
     index: {
       // entry for the page
       entry: 'src/main.ts',
       chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
     },
   },
   devServer: {
     hot: true,
     liveReload: true
   },

   configureWebpack: {
  
     devtool: false,
     
     plugins: [
       require('unplugin-vue-components/webpack')({
         resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
       }),
       require('unplugin-auto-import/webpack')({
         resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
       }),
     ],
   }
 };
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "types": [
          "webpack-env", "offscreencanvas"
        ],
        "paths": {
          "@/*": [
            "src/*"
          ]
        },
        "lib": [
          "esnext",
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "scripthost"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue",
        "tests/**/*.ts",
        "tests/**/*.tsx"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
      ]
    }
```

package.json

```
 {
      "name": "test-js",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "export ENVSOURCEMAPMODE=inline-source-map && vue-cli-service build --mode production && ./copyfiles.sh",
        "build-debug": "export ENVSOURCEMAPMODE=inline-source-map && vue-cli-service build && ./copyfiles.sh",
        "watch": "npm run build-debug && npm-watch"
      },
      "watch": {
        "build-debug": {
          "patterns": [
            "src"
          ],
          "extensions": "vue,css,js,ts"
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@types/offscreencanvas": "^2019.6.4",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "element-plus": "^2.0.5",
        "@element-plus/icons-vue": "^0.2.4",

        "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.39",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.51.0",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "typescript": "^4.5.4",
        "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.5.9",
        "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.17.11",
        "vue-plugin-webextension-i18n": "^0.1.2"
      }
    }
```

Comment: I believe this is not a common problem, so you need to find root cause first. Does a different build cause errors? That it renames exports means that they should either break on import, or are not used at all. In this setup unplugin is uncommon and may be the first thing to investigate

Comment: No, the different build does not cause errors. I disabled unplugin, but behavior is the same (sometimes producing rather different output).

Comment: I imagine the build process has some algorithmic like decision tree that reaches the same end result but doesn't always take the same path every time resulting in slightly different code.  If there are no issues with the final app itself, I don't think there's anything you should do to "correct" this behavior.

Comment: @youduh, I'd agree with you if I wouldn't have been obliged to provide source files + build instructions to the Mozilla Extension reviewers in order to approve my extension. The extension uses a minified copy of the JS file, and they should check the source file and then compile it to get the same result as the minified JS.

Comment: It seems, I'm close to finding the cause of the problem. Some of the VUE files were using TS files located outside of the project's root folder. The problem disappeared since I moved these files under the root folder and respectively changed the links. I have no idea how placing some source files outside of the root dir affects the decision tree, but it really does.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was in the project structure:

```
├── Common library
│   └── library.ts
├── Project root
│   ├── src      
│   │    └── ....
```

The project used a common TypeScript library located outside of the project root.

**Solution**: Putting a symlink inside of the project root and altering webpack.config.json (resolve: {symlinks: false}) fixed this issue.
Seems like the decision tree is not stable when some files are located outside of the project root.

Comment: Having a similar issue where 1 out of 10 builds is different, even producing runtime errors. My project uses yarn workspaces and a lot of (TS) code lives outside the Vue app project root, and already have symlinks set to `false`, per recommendation here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/troubleshooting.html#symbolic-links-in-node-modules. Is there maybe anything else you have changed in the webpack config that resolved this issue for you?